# Can't find .android folder in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

Where can I find `.android` in Ubuntu as I want to use `debug.keystore` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in the home directory of the user that have installed the sdk

Answer (score 17):

go to your home folder and pres ctrl+h and voila!

Comment: what does it do ?

Comment: it shows the hidden files :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm new using Ubuntu so this shortcut is useful :D

Answer (score 12):

Type this in a shell:

```
find ~ -name ".android"
```

Answer (score 10):

Files with "." at the begining are hidden by default. Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I have found it in [home path]/.android

Answer (score 4):

Let me provide more information on @adham's answer.

This .android folder is available inside the home directory. If you don't see this folder then consider that it is hidden. To make this folder visible, go to **Edit->Preferences** and then mark "**Show hidden and backup files**".

Once you tick this checkbox, you will sure get this folder, now debug.keystore is available inside the .android directory.