# How to show the system navigation bar in an emulator

Tags: android, emulation, navigationbar

How can I enable the system navigationbar (the one including the HOME/BACK/MENU) on Jellybean emulator?

Googling this, somebody said it can be done by changing the property `qemu.hw.mainkeys`, however I can't find where to set this constant.
can somebody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure the Android Emulator to show onscreen buttons like the new Galaxy Nexus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873532/how-to-configure-the-android-emulator-to-show-onscreen-buttons-like-the-new-gala)

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old question. But, the trick is the following:

Navigate to `.android/avd/virtual-device.avd`, and change the following values in the following files:

`config.ini`: `hw.mainKeys=no, hw.keyboard=no`

`hardware-qemu.ini`: `hw.mainKeys = no, hw.keyboard = no`

That should disable the `navigation bar` on the virtual device.

**Note:** To enable the use of the keyboard, you just have to `set` these parameters to yes.

Comment: where do i find ".android"

Comment: @icyNerd it depends. On Windows, I think it lives under your username C:\Users\{username}\.android
On the other hand, for other OS, you would have to google the location. Here are a couple of links with that answer for Ubuntu and Mac: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705932/cant-find-android-folder-in-ubuntu), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532063/finding-android-sdk-on-mac-and-adding-to-path)